# chaining Jquery Deferred objects with promises

Tags: jquery

```
function addAccountData(data) {


var queryResults = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;

var key;
var displayProps = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("qProps")).split(",");
var keyIndex;
var resultIndexes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < queryResults[0].Cells.results.length; i++) {
    key = queryResults[0].Cells.results[i].Key;
    keyIndex = displayProps.indexOf(key);

    if (keyIndex > -1) {
        resultIndexes.push(i);
    }
}

    var promises = [];
    for (var h = 0; h < queryResults.length; h++) {
        var cellValues = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < resultIndexes.length; i++) {
            cellValues.push(queryResults[h].Cells.results[resultIndexes[i]].Value);
        }

       // getAccountInfo(cellValues);
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        //add data from SharePoint Accounts list

            if (cellValues[4] != null) {
                $.when(getAccountInfo(cellValues)).done(function (data) {
                    tempResults.push(data);
                    deferred.resolve(tempResults);
                });
            }

        promises.push(deferred);
    }

 $.when.apply($,promises).done(function() {
     alert('yes');
     spinner.stop();
 }, 
  function(e) {
     console.log("My ajax failed");
 });
}
```

This function in my jquery code uses deferred objects and promises to resolve an asynchronous function. An array of promises are defined and using the `.when` and `.apply` the array is passed. However, after the deferred.resolve is called for each promise, it does not callback the statements inside the `$.when.apply($,promises).done(function() ... )` is never called. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing more information, including the `getAccountInfo()` function. Also, there's no reason to artificially create your `$.Deferred()` objects to store to your array--just add the results of the `getAccountInfo()`, as this appears to already return a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only suspect that `getAccountInfo()` already returns a promise (most probably a jQuery XHR object).

That means you don't need your own deferred infrastructure, you can simply use the jqXhr objects directly.

I've rewritten your code, for the fun of it without any explicit loops.

```
function addAccountData(data) {
    var table = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table;
    var displayProps = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("qProps")).split(",");
    var requests = table.Rows.results.map(function (row) {
        // find Cells whose .Key is in displayProps and get their .Value
        return row.Cells.results.filter(function (cell) {
            return displayProps.indexOf(cell.Key) > -1;
        }).map(function (cell) {
            return cell.Value;
        });
    }).filter(function (cellValues) {
        return cellValues[4] !== null;
    }).map(getAccountInfo);

    $.when.apply($, requests).always(function () {
        spinner.stop();
    }).fail(function(e) {
        console.log("Ajax failed");
    });
}
```

This maps your Rows from the `queryResults` to arrays of Cell values and maps *them* through `getAccountInfo()` (which I assume returns individual jqXhr objects).

So effectively it maps your rows to Ajax request promises, which are handled by `$.when`. You probably want your spinner to stop *always*, not only on overall success.